# Unable to read video file greater than 2gb

Tags: c#, asp.net

In an ASP.NET application, I am using the code shown below to read video files from a shared path and play them in the browser. It is working for files which are less than 300 mb in size, but it is throwing out of memory exceptions for 650 mb file and for greater than 2 gb it is throwing

> The file is too long. This operation is currently limited to supporting files less than 2 gigabytes in size.

My code:

```
ImpersonationHelper.Impersonate(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Domain"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"],ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"], delegate
{  
    FileBuffer = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);

    if (FileBuffer != null)
    {
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.ContentType = contenttype;
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline");
        Response.AddHeader("content-length", FileBuffer.Length.ToString());

        Response.BinaryWrite(FileBuffer);
        Response.Flush();                       

        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        Response.Close();
        Response.End();                            
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading entire file into memory is bad idea. Instead of using `FileBuffer` array you can do below:

```
// ...
using (var stream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    Response.AddHeader("content-length", stream.Length.ToString());
    stream.CopyTo(Response.OutputStream);
}
```

You should also remove this line `Response.Buffer = true;` and add `Response.BufferOutput = false;` in the beginning. With `BufferOutput == true` web server saves entire output to memory and only after this sends it to client. We don't want this to happen.

Comment: Hi thanks for the prompt response. Can you please extend the code ? currently it is showing some random numbers & symbols instead of playing video in the browser. Did i miss anything?  Also above 2gb file it is throwing "Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program". For less than 2gb files no exceptions.

Comment: You should fill other headers like in your code. I just showed how to fill content-length header and copy file to output stream.

Comment: Hi Zergatul, thanks for the answer. able to render video files which are less than 1 Gb, but the video stopped playing after a while throwing " not enough storage is available to process this command" any idea on this ? and also still getting "Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program" for video files >2gb.

Comment: @SrikanthA is this the exception in code, or error from browser you are using?

Comment: Hi Zergatul: Is there any way to disable download option? Requirement is to prevent user from downloading

Comment: @SrikanthA if user is smart enough, he can always download the video. I am not aware if there is an easy way to prevent downloading for non-experienced users. You should better create new topic for this, or try to find similar question